# How to run tests using gorm with mysql in golang?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm puzzled.
I try to run test cases using gorm with mysql in golang and I wanna buile MySQL just for testing, but it does not run safely.

I wanna use this package [go-test-mysqld](https://github.com/lestrrat/go-test-mysqld)

Error message is below.
`panic: sql: Register called twice for driver mysql`

My code is

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    mysqld, err := mysqltest.NewMysqld(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("runTests: failed", err)
    }

    defer mysqld.Stop()
    dbm, err = gorm.Open("mysqld", mysqld.Datasource("test", "", "", 0 ))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("db connection error:", err)
    }

    defer dbm.Close()
    code := m.Run()
    os.Exit(code)
}
```

What is the problems in my code?
Or is it impossible to build another mysql in using gorm?

Do you have some ideas?